# PostgreSQL ILIKE on concatinated columns not working

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query using ILIKE on a user's name in PostgreSQL.  There are columns for first_name and last_name, and I'd like the search term to match against the two concatenated, with a space between, so that a user may search for either, or a full name using one input.  "John"  "Doe" or "John Doe".

This always returns no results:

`SELECT * FROM user_profiles WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name ILIKE '%ryan%'`

This always returns the one result I am expecting:

`SELECT * FROM user_profiles WHERE first_name ILIKE '%ryan%'`

Based on everything I've read, the first query should work as I am expecting, but it doesn't.  No results and no errors.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query would return no results if `last_name` were `NULL` (and similarly if `first_name` were `NULL`).

So, try this instead:

```
WHERE first_name || ' ' || COALESCE(last_name, '') ILIKE '%ryan%'
```

or:

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) ILIKE '%ryan%'
```

The `concat_ws()` function ignores arguments that are not `NULL` (except for the first argument).

Comment: You are correct, `last_name` was null.  I discovered that just after posting and was trying to fix with `(first_name::text || ' ' || last_name::text)` but that did not work either.  You answers do work and return the expected results.  Thank you! (will accept in 5 mins once it allows me)